# 'requests' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python-3.x

I'm running Python 3.8.3 and getting an error as follows:

> 'requests' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

To verify that I have the requests installed, I tried:

```
install pip
```

and was told that the requirement was already satisfied.

I read elsewhere that there could be an issue if the requests version was out of sync with python and the advised remedy was as follows:

```
pip install --target=/usr/lib/python3.8.3/requests
```

which ran successfully but did not remedy the error.

Any help from the community would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Requests officially supports Python 2.7 & 3.4 – 3.7.

Also type **python** in your console and press enter. Them type **import requests** if it does so without producing any error then its installed correctly.

But I would strongly recommend downgrading your python version to one required by requests and then performing the above steps.